# How can we create iPhone-like spinners in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

Default spinners on the iPhone look a lot better than on Android.  It looks like at least one Android app (UrbanSpoon) has been able to replicate this control, and it's awesome: http://www.urbanspoon.com/android

Anyone have any ideas on how to create this?  Code would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest you bounty this if it is that important to you. Or if you work in a company that needs it contact urbanspoon and see if you can buy the widget from them.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you say ,you can try
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/advanced-android-ui-wheelpicker/

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't need support for the trackball, then all it will take is [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) along with some minor tweaks to some existing [JavaScript that impersonates Apple's UIPickerView](https://web.archive.org/web/20180804201110/http://cubiq.org:80/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch) to create applications like this.

[image: Fancy Spinner Image]

A majority of the hard work has been done by Matteo Spinelli so start by [downloading his code](https://web.archive.org/web/20120603073832/http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sw/sw.zip?v=1.4) and then apply these changes to `spinningwheel.js`.  His code wants to pop up the picker from the bottom of the screen with cancel and done buttons so we need to modify a few lines to eliminate this behavior.

```
--- spinningwheel.js.orig   2010-05-26 00:17:00.411954051 -0700
+++ spinningwheel.js    2010-05-26 00:16:32.319010720 -0700
@@ -67,12 +67,10 @@
 
    onOrientationChange: function (e) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
-       this.swWrapper.style.top = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + 'px';
        this.calculateSlotsWidth();
    },
    
    onScroll: function (e) {
-       this.swWrapper.style.top = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + 'px';
    },
 
    lockScreen: function (e) {
@@ -113,9 +111,9 @@
        // Create the Spinning Wheel main wrapper
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'sw-wrapper';
-       div.style.top = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + 'px';     // Place the SW down the actual viewing screen
+       div.style.top = 0;
        div.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform';
-       div.innerHTML = '<div id="sw-header"><div id="sw-cancel">Cancel</' + 'div><div id="sw-done">Done</' + 'div></' + 'div><div id="sw-slots-wrapper"><div id="sw-slots"></' + 'div></' + 'div><div id="sw-frame"></' + 'div>';
+       div.innerHTML = '<div id="sw-slots-wrapper"><div id="sw-slots"></' + 'div></' + 'div><div id="sw-frame"></' + 'div>';
 
        document.body.appendChild(div);
 
@@ -164,8 +162,6 @@
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this, true);              // Reposition SW on page scroll
 
        // Cancel/Done buttons events
-       document.getElementById('sw-cancel').addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
-       document.getElementById('sw-done').addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
 
        // Add scrolling to the slots
        this.swFrame.addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
@@ -174,9 +170,6 @@
    open: function () {
        this.create();
 
-       this.swWrapper.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = 'ease-out';
-       this.swWrapper.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '400ms';
-       this.swWrapper.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0, -260px, 0)';
    },
    
    
@@ -191,8 +184,6 @@
 
        this.swFrame.removeEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
 
-       document.getElementById('sw-cancel').removeEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
-       document.getElementById('sw-done').removeEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
 
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
```

Additionally, the `index.html` he provides isn't exactly what you want so replace it with this one and then copy the html, css, js, and png files into the assets directory of your project.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="spinningwheel.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spinningwheel.js?v=1.4"></script>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        
   function getData() {
    var results = SpinningWheel.getSelectedValues();
    window.android.sendResults(results.values.join(' ')  );
   }
            
   function notifyAndroid() {
    window.android.readyForJavascript('');
   }
        
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="javascript:notifyAndroid()"></body>
</html>
```

Create an Activity that enables JavaScript in a WebView and has callbacks for it to return the selection.

```
public class FancySpinner extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.GetSelectedTimeButton))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:getData()");
                    }
                });
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidBridge(), "android");
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
    private class AndroidBridge {
        public void sendResults(final String arg) {
            Toast.makeText(FancySpinner.this, arg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void readyForJavascript(final String arg) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.addSlot({ " +
                    "1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3,  4:  4,  5:  5,  6:  6," +
                    "7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12 });");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.addSlot({ " +
                    "1: 'AM', 2: 'PM'});");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.open();");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, modify your layout so has a WebView with its height set appropriately.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/WebView01" 
        android:background="#77CC0000"
        android:layout_height="215dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false" />
    <Button 
        android:text="Read Selected Time" 
        android:id="@+id/GetSelectedTimeButton" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The Wheel is not spinning!
You may want to revise the your javascript code

Comment: @Tawani I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.  Perhaps you should see if your touch events cause the wheel to spin when you view [Matteo's demo page](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sw/) within the Android Browser application.

Comment: It spins for me in 2.1, but not 1.6

Comment: JonF could you give me this code,i cannot run it, thanks wp19831014@gmail.com

Comment: Wow, Its really awesome! What i am really looking for!

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like it is just a list view with some special styling to make it look rounded.  In terms of behavior, I don't think it would be any different from a ListView where the middle item is considered the selected value.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If you use the widget, it's actually more like three ListViews pushed together. Just wondering about ideas to make that happen...

Comment: Yeah, sorry thats what I meant.  Each individual spinner is a ListView, so that picture has 3 together.