# add animation to android-wheel

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I'm trying to update the project at http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ to act like the iPhone spinner/Urban Spoon App.

I want to add acceleration/deceleration to scrolling, as well as a spinning animation. I just don't know where to start. I was able to get the whole control to slide with the built in android transitions by adding the effects to the onTouchEvent in the WheelView [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/WheelView.java).

Obviously that's not very useful and I don't think the transition animations are what I need. Can anybody take a look at this and at the very least suggest how to start modifying it to do what I want? Any help would be appreciated. I don't expect anybody to implement this and hand it to me but I'm confused and frustrated with this, so I would like some kind of guidance.

I've tried the webview method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909249/how-can-we-create-iphone-like-spinners-in-android) but it loads and runs kind of slow and it doesn't  animate either so I'd rather just use the customized Android controls if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now the android-wheel project supports animation. So, you can take a look at code to investigate how it works.