# Use database with Iphone like spinner with android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, ide, spinner

I am new to developing anything and  want to make an Iphone like spinner that pulls information from database and return info contained in database

I have checked all the spinners out on [How can we create iPhone-like spinners in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909249/how-can-we-create-iphone-like-spinners-in-android) and like the I phone one it is based of off javascript and html

want my database to be similar to this
http://www.portlandbolt.com/technicalinformation/bolt-torque-chart.html

any ideas on how to accomplish this or code snippets that would help.

I am also having problems setting up a database I am using Eclipse Helios and have been unable to install dbEdit and jdbc drivers tried many tutorials but no luck, would it be better to try a different IDE like netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about JDBC when programming for Android.  Take a look at [the notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html), for a decent introduction to using a database from an Android app.

For a good looking spinner, take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

I recommend that you use the standard Eclipse tooling, as it works well (in my experience), and it has a lot of community support.