# Android rolling selection menu

Tags: android, scrollview

I saw this on a UI design from graphicriver ([link to original](http://graphicriver.net/item/tabletphone-user-interface-professional-set/96335?ref=cazoobi))

[image]

I wanted to know if this is possible to make in android, has anyone come across something like this?  Would it be a scrollview with a background that moves in sync with the selection?

Let me know how you guys think this can be made?

Comment: or can it be done with a spinner?

Comment: here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909249/how-can-we-create-iphone-like-spinners-in-android

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/