# Creating a dual spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to recreate an Apple app in Android. The Apple app includes a dual spinner (see image below). You can select a letter on the left hand side, and it finds the first item that starts with that letter on the right hand side (or rather, the last item of the previous letter, so the user is more likely to choose something and not just accept the first item).

[image: Dual Spinner]

Is there any way of achieving something similar in Android? I'm thinking of trying to use a dialog with a couple of ListViews, but I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree there?

Comment: EXact Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909249/how-can-we-create-iphone-like-spinners-in-android

Comment: ListView + SomeAdapter + AlphabetIndexer ... do not implement stuff like this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: @AurA: Thank you, I did search quite hard but didn't find that. However, I am not trying to mimic the look and feel of Apple here, I'm trying to produce a functionally equivalent control using native Android views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to achieve the result I wanted using a custom dialog containing 2 ListViews side by side (with another View acting as a divider between them).